# How to construct a kernel from a function?

Tags: functions, matrix, image-processing, kernel, list-manipulation

I would like to convolve an image with a mathematical function. I understand that I need to have the mathematical function in a matrix form. How can I build it?

Thanks

Comment: Please elaborate. At the moment the question seems quite broad / unspecific. Also, please try to explain your *Mathematica* angle and show what you have tried (if available).

Comment: Are you looking for `Array` or `Table`? Those evaluate a function resp. an expression for every cell in a matrix

Comment: At the moment I convolved an image with a Gaussian using `ImageConvolve[Image,GaussianMatrix[{b, a}]]`. Now I want to convolve the  same image with different functions (i.e. Sinc[x,y], or other mathematical functions). But I don't know how to transform the mathematical function to kernel or matrix

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just sample your function over a 2D window with a `Table`.

```
f[x_,y_]:= 1-2*Sinc[2(x^2 + y^2)]
step = .2;
kern = Table[f[x,y], {x, -3, 3, step}, {y, -3, 3, step}];
```

The dimensions of the kernel can be returned with `Dimensions[kern]`. Experiment with values of step and window sizes. Now just do an `ImageConvolve[img,kern]` and optionally use `ImageAdjust` to normalize and remove filter gain:

[image: Custom Kernel]